# What is a JSHTML file?

Tags: html, jshtml

I tried to search online about what a .jshtml file is, but in vain...

The .jshtml file looks very much like a html file, but I don't understand why it is called jshtml and how it gets created?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [check this](http://james.padolsey.com/cool-stuff/introducing-jshtml/)

Comment: Where did you find that file?

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/cool-stuff/introducing-jshtml/ Never used it myself but this article seems quite interesting

Comment: Hi @ElmerDantas I found the article, but didn't understand it. Is the .jshtml file used to inject information into another html file?

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. I just received this file through email..

Comment: Then ask them what kind of file this is and how to use it. `.jshtml` without explanation is not something they can expect everyone to know about.

Comment: It was a "js library" attempt to manage javascript based HTML templates in an "easy" way. Concept was interesting it's a dead project and there are much many other alternatives. Just look at: https://www.bearfruit.org/2014/01/20/node-js-template-showdown-jshtml-compared/

Comment: @Penny as I understood, JSHTML is a view engine that you can use to write HTML with some advantages (like jade, ejs, pug and mustache) but I didn't see any real use for it. I think you can get your doubts solved with [James](https://twitter.com/padolsey) who wrote the article. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Elmer. :)